# Nuget Packager the default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, nuget-package, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I changed the project type I am packaging from .net framework v4.6 to .net standard 2.0, now the build definition is failing in Nuget packager step and I am getting this error message.

> [error]The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild
>   XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format,
>   please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
>   to the  element. If the project has been authored in the old
>   1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.

After researching about this error I understand that the NuGet packer step doesn't work on SDK-based csproj formats.

What is the best alternative available? I found the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44002024/vsts-build-nuget-packager-dont-work), but I can not find the command pack within the available commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I resolved this issue:

1- Add package metadata to .csproj file.

2- Go to project properties -> package and check "Generate NuGet package on build".

3- In Build definition add the following tasks:

a- NuGet Restore:

- Set path to solution.
- Select Feeds in my NuGet.config as Feeds to use.
- Set path to Nuget.config (Usually project root "src\nuget.config").

b- Visual Studio Build:

- Set path to solution.
- Platform: something like $(BuildPlatform).
- Configuration: something like $(BuildConfiguration).

c- Copy and Publish Build Artifacts:

- In contents enter *.nupkg.
- Set Copy Root, Artifact name, and Artifact type.

Comment: Do you just skip the packing step while build step already generates the package?

Comment: Yes exactly, "Generate NuGet package on build" should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

While the `pack` command does not appear in the dropdown, you can enter it manually into the field.

Comment: @YahyaHussein Have you resolved the issue by Martin's answer? any update?

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT No, Actually I used a totally different way, Martin's answer was a part of the solution, if you have an answer please paste it because it might be better than the way I am using, if you are searching for an answer, then I will explain what I did when I have the chance.

Comment: @YahyaHussein If you have resolved the issue , please share the solution as an answer here, thanks.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT check the answer